# Tensorflow accuracy issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I've wrote my first Tensorflow program ( using my own data) . It works well at least it doesn't crash!  but I'm getting  a wired accuracy values either 0 oder 1 ?

```
................................. 
the previous part of the code, is only about handeling csv file an getting Data in correct format / shapes
......................................................
# Tensoflow
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,len(Training_Data[0])],name='Train_data')# each input has a 457 lenght

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, numberOFClasses],name='Labels')#

#w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([len(Training_Data[0]),numberOFClasses]),name='Weights')
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([len(Training_Data[0]),numberOFClasses],stddev=1./10),name='Weights')

b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([numberOFClasses]),name='Biases')
model = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w),b)

y =  tf.nn.softmax(model)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
#cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for j in range(len(train_data)):
    if(np.shape(train_data) == (batchSize,numberOFClasses)):
        sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:train_data[j],y_:np.reshape(train_labels[j],(batchSize,numberOFClasses)) })

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,"float"))

accuracy_vector= []
current_class =[] 
for i in range(len(Testing_Data)):
    if( np.shape(Testing_Labels[i]) == (numberOFClasses,)):
        accuracy_vector.append(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:np.reshape(Testing_Data[i],(1,457)),y_:np.reshape(Testing_Labels[i],(1,19))}))#,i)#,Test_Labels[i])
        current_class.append(int(Test_Raw[i][-1]))
```

ploting the`accuracy_vector`  delivers the following :

[[image]]

any idea what I'm missing here ?

thanks a lot for any hint !

Comment: Are you sure the training actually happens ? The test 'if(np.shape(train_data) == (batchSize,numberOFClasses)):' should not be true, since train_data is more likely of shape (n_samples, num_features), with n_samples being the total number of samples or the batch size, and num_features seems to be 457 in your case...

Comment: @gdelab  I could not thank you enough,   the if statement is only for the end  of the because the program crashes as the end. But how can check if the training is happening , I mean  the if statement is only once not valid . but how to check if the training is really happening  ?

Comment: You can just add a 'print("We should be training")' just before or after 'sess.run(training_step, ...)', in the same 'if' statement. If it prints something, then you train !

Comment: you got a point the training is happening, sorry for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing on batches of size 1, so either the prediction is good or it's false, so you can only get 0 or 1 accuracy:

`accuracy_vector.append(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:np.reshape(Testing_Data[i],(1,457)),y_:np.reshape(Testing_Labels[i],(1,19))}))#,i)#,Test_Labels[i])`

Just use a bigger batch size :
 `accuracy_vector.append(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:np.reshape(Testing_Data[i:i+batch_size],(batch_size,457)),y_:np.reshape(Testing_Labels[i:i+batch_size],(batch_size,19))}))`

Answer (score 2):

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
```

`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` wants unscaled logits.
From the doc:

> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

this means that the line `y =  tf.nn.softmax(model)` is wrong.

Instead, you want to pass unscaled logits to that function, thus:

```
y = model
```

Moreover, once you fix this problem, if the network doesn't work, try to lower the learning rate from 0.01 to something about 1e-3 or 1e-4. (I tell you this because 1e-2 usually is an "high" learning rate)

Comment: thanks for your reply I've edited the code the 1e-5 learning rate , but still no change in the result `?

Comment: Do you changed the logits parameter too?

Comment: what do you mean ? I've changed the learning rate to 1e-20 and nothing change, gdelab suggestion makes sense I'm trying to handel the reshaping  but I still don't get your point ! thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Before the suggestion about the learning rate, I told you to change `y` from `tf.nn.softmax(model)` to `model`. Have you done this? Moreover yeah, increase the batch size when you run the evaluation otherwise the value will always be 0 or 1, right

Comment: yes I've done but seems that my model never trained! :/ my fault